# Create String Combinations That Include k Amount of Consecutive Strings From The Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

If we have the following array:

```
["it", "wkppv", "ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz"]
```

And if we're trying to get all possible string combinations of **k**  (in this case **3**), without randomization, we should get the following strings:

```
'itwkppvixoyx'
'wkppvixoyx3452
'ixoyx3452zzzzzzzzzzzz'
```

Because of course,

```
"it" + "wkppv" + "ixoyx" = "itwkppvixoyx",

"wkppv" + "ixoyx" + "3452" = "wkppvixoyx3452",

"ixoyx" + "3452" + "zzzzzzzzzzzz" = "ixoyx3452zzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

But I've not been able to figure out a way to create these strings.

I understand how to create strings that include the *first* string and the *last* string based on **k**, for example:

```js
function createStrings (array, k) {
    let strings = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length - (k - 1); i++) {
        strings.push(`${array[i]}${(array[i + (k-1)])}`);
    }    
    return strings;
}

console.log(createStrings(["it", "wkppv", "ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz"], 3));
```

But of course these are missing the "middle" element(s).

What if **k** is 2 or 4? I need to find a way to create string combinations that include **k** amount of *consecutive* strings from the array. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can use something like sliding window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is problem of sliding window, where window size is `k`.

Solution is to make a initial window then slide it towards end.

My documented solution is here

```js
function createCombinations(stringArray, k) {
    // Define an empty array to store combinations
    let result = [];

    // Make a combination for starting window
    let initialWindow = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        // '+' operator, by default string concatenation
        initialWindow += stringArray[i];
    }

    // Add it to Result array
    result.push(initialWindow);

    // Iterate over remaining stringArray element
    for (let i = k; i < stringArray.length; i++) {

        // For debugging
        // console.log('Initial Combination->', initialWindow, initialWindow.length);
        // console.log('Remove first entry->', stringArray[i-k], stringArray[i-k].length);
        // console.log('After remove->', initialWindow.slice(stringArray[i-k].length));

        // Remove k previous element and add next element
        initialWindow = initialWindow.slice(stringArray[i-k].length) + stringArray[i];

        // console.log('After add next->', initialWindow);

        result.push(initialWindow);
    }

    return result;
}

/* Tests */

console.log(createCombinations(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight'], 3));
console.log(createCombinations(['This', 'is', 'Some', 'Random', 'String'], 4));
console.log(createCombinations(['What', 'Am', 'I', 'Doing', 'Here', 'Some', 'Other'], 2));
console.log(createCombinations(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 3));
```

Note: If you pass numbers without `' '`, it will evaluate the expression instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter alternative with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
const createStrings = (a, k) => a.slice(k - 1).map((v, i) => a.slice(i, i + k).join(''))

console.log( createStrings([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4) )
console.log( createStrings(["it", "wkppv", "ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz"], 3) )
```